# Getting 'ActiveX component can't create object: "Quicktest.Application" when launching UFT remotely

Tags: remote-access, qtp, hp-uft, activexobject, alm

I am using below Driver script code to Run my tests in remote Machine (e.g. MachineName: xyz) and there is no UFT installed in my local machine (e.g. machineName: abc). Here both the machines are in same domain and DCOME settings also changed.

```vbs
remoteMachineFullName = "xyz"
Set App = CreateObject("QuickTest.Application", remoteMachineFullName)
App.Launch
App.Visible = True
```

I am getting below error when i invoked driver script from local machine.

> Error: 'ActiveX component can't create object: "Quicktest.Application"

**Question:** Is it required to have UFT installed in **locale machine** to create AOM object and run it in remote machine? If I have UFT Installed in my local machine then I am not getting any error.

Comment: Have you set DCOM Configuration Properties on the Remote Computer...?

Comment: @ManishChristian Yes I did DCOM configuration as well and able to invoke remote machine. But the problem is, If i have UFT installed in my local machine then only Iam able to invoke remote machine other wise getting same error.

Comment: Have you installed UFT on remote machine using the same user as running your script from local system?

Comment: @ManishChristian: No, Both the machines are having different accounts.

Comment: That might be the issue. Try re-installing UFT with same user.